# How to filter results with special characters using jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, special-characters, datatables, html-entities

I am using the jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net) plugin in my application, and many of my table rows and filters have special characters, specifically ampersands (&) in them.  When I try to filter on these columns, all records disappear and it displays "no matching records found".

I have tried encoding (i.e. htmlspecialchars) and decoding (i.e. htmlspecialchars_decode) the strings before they are printed onto the page, but neither seems to be working.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gkdcZ/3/

Any ideas why this might be happening, and how I can fix it?

HTML:

```
<select id="filter_col_1" name="filter_col_1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="A&B">A&B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>   
</select>

<tr>
    <td>A&B</td>
    <td>Jones, Brandon</td>
    <td>01/02/2003</td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#filter_col_1").change( function() { 
    $('#results').dataTable().fnFilter(
        '\\b' + $("#filter_col_1").val() + '\\b',
        1,
        true,
        false
    );
} );
```

**UPDATE #1:**
Issue appears to only happen when you limit the column.  See [DataTables API](http://datatables.net/api).  Works fine when parameter is set to "null". http://jsfiddle.net/gkdcZ/4/

**UPDATE #2:**
A bit closer.  Adding in a function to replace HTML Entities works for certain characters (i.e. ampersands), but does not work for other characters (i.e. exclamation points and question marks).  See http://jsfiddle.net/cz6Bs/4/

```
'\\b' + htmlEntities($('#filter_col_1').val()) + '\\b'

function htmlEntities(str) {
return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                  .replace(/>/g,     '&gt;')
                  .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Comment: can you replace the '&' with 'and' ?  like this: str_replace("&", " and ", $input);

Comment: I don't get what your trying do to. Can you post your Javascript code please ?

Comment: Just added in JavaScript above.  I am trying to filter the search results based on a dropdown box selection.  My dropdown box has some items with special characters, which is causing the problem.

Comment: Just added a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gkdcZ/3/ (try filtering for "A&B").

Comment: A&B works just fine for me... FF11 and in Chrome... what browser are you using? try in a different one...

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I am using FF11 too, and this is what it shows me: http://snag.gy/iNlFh.jpg I have tried it in Chrome 18 and IE9.  Same thing.

Comment: sorry , my bad i checked the search...

Comment: I noticed that too, strange it works in the "global" search, but not the dropdown.

Comment: $('#results').dataTable().fnFilter(
            $("#filter_col_1").val(),

            null,
           
            false
        );

Answer (score 6):

There is indeed a bug with dataTables that causes problems with any special chars so you'll have to escape them.

http://jsfiddle.net/cz6Bs/

Note: I added XRegExp as another resource for the escaping.
http://xregexp.com/

Comment: Reference on the bug: 
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5879/fnfilter-does-not-decode-column-data-containing-html-special-characters/p1

Comment: This was only working because you changed the second argument back to null (see other answer listed here and my updated posted above).  If you change your code back to filter on the specific column (i.e. 0) it doesn't work even with using XRegExp http://jsfiddle.net/cz6Bs/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#results').dataTable();
$("#filter_col_1").change( function() { 
    $('#results').dataTable().fnFilter(  
'\\b' + htmlEntities($('#filter_col_1').val()) + '\\b', 
 0,
true,
false
);
 } );  


});    
function htmlEntities(str) {
return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g,     '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Comment: this is getting closer to a fix! :)  It doesn't seem to work however if there are other characters like an exclamation point or question mark in the dropdown and results.  http://jsfiddle.net/cz6Bs/4/  (see options C and D now)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#results').dataTable().fnFilter(
        $("#filter_col_1").val(),
        null,
        true
    );
```

set it to filter on all columns , works now...

Comment: For other reasons, I for sure need to keep the regex in place, and the specific column filtering is fairly important too.

Comment: ok set regex back to true , works... dunno about the "why works only with null in column field...